# AWS ECR Login error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

AWS ECR Login error:
command: aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-south-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin {id}.dkr.ecr.{region}.amazonaws.com

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the
> GetAuthorizationToken operation: User:
> arn:aws:iam::{id}:{user/username}not authorized to perform:
> ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: * because no identity-based
> policy allows the ecr:GetAuthorizationToken action Error: Cannot
> perform an interactive login from a non TTY device.

If I add `*` in `Resource` I am able to Login:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPullImageTag",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "iam:GetAccountAuthorizationDetails"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ecr:{region}:{id}:{repository}/{repository}"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/environment": "{taganame}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I made this policy only for pulling an image for specific user and for specific tag of repository.

Comment: Does this work if you declare the resource without the "[  ]"? Like `"Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:{region}:{id}:{repository}/{repository}",`

Comment: I have multiple repositories, and its working. I want to add multiple tag based access control